# Dovecot configuration with pop3 server to client email setup

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, config, pop3, dovecot

hope you fine. I am working on my vps email configuration setting. I configured the the postfix which is working on the mail-to-mail server and now i want to make a configuration with server-to-client email configuration, I already installed dovecot-core, dovecot-imapd, and dovecot-pop3d on my vps and also i generated the SSL decertification which is fine and by default at the time purchasing the VPS, and i am using the nginx server.Whenever i want to send email from my mobile to my vps it shows me the error message that your ssl certificate needs to be installed correctly. Now i want to configure my SSL certificate which is freely available on the Hostinger platform on my VPS, but I don't know how to do it. I already take help of AI but it does not give me the proper solution. will you please tell me what should i do now? I bought my vps on hostinger platform and now i want to embed the free SSL on my website but i don't know how to do this? Furthermore tell me is the free ssl certificates are working fine are there are risks availabe with it ?

I installed all the dependencies and package installed libraries.

````
 1885  systemctl status postfix
 1886  systemctl status dovecot
 1889  etc/nignx/site-enabled
 1890  etc/nignx/sites-enabled
 1891  cd /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
 1892  ls -a
 1893  exit
 1894  ls -a
 1895  cd /etc/nginx/
 1896  ls -a
 1897  cd sites-enabled
 1898  ls -a
 1899  cd ..
 1900  ls -a
 1901  cd /dovecot/
 1902  cd /etc/dovecot/
 1903  ls -a
 1904  cat dovecot.conf
 1905  sudo nano dovecot.conf
 1906  cd ..
 1907  cd /postfix/
 1908  cd /etc/postfix/
 1909  ls -a
 1910  sudo nano main.cf
 1911  cd ~
 1915  nmap -v localhost
 1916  Maildir
 1920  sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log
 1921  mail
 1922  ls -a
 1923  mail
 1924  ls -a
 1925  sudo tail -f /var/log/mail.log
 1926  systemctl status imap
 1927  systemctl status imapd
 1928  netstat -v localhost
 1929  nmap -v localhost
 1930  sudo apt-get install dovecot-imapd dovecot-pop3d
 1931  cat /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
 1932  sudo nano /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
 1933  ls -a
 1934  nmap -v localhost
 1935  cd /etc/ssl/certs/
 1936  ls
 1937  sudo nano ssl-cert-snakeoil
 1938  sudo nano ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
 1939  cd ~
 1940  sudo certbot renew --dry-run
 1941  exit
 1942  ls -a
 1943  history
 1944  ls -a
 1945  cd /etc/
 1946  ls -a
 1947  cd /nginx/
 1948  cd ..
 1949  clear
 1950  history```
This is my working history
````